# Format or Alignment the lines of CSHTML file in C# programmatically

Tags: c#, html, razor, roslyn, asp.net-core-3.1

I have implemented the project of migrating Asp.Net WebApi / MVC into Asp.Net Core 3.1.While transforming or updating class file(".cs") and cshtml file(".cshtml"), lines of those files have not proper alignment.

Example like as below:

**Sample.cs**

```
using System;
namespace TestFile1.Source
{    public class SampleFile
{   [AllowHtml]
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

[ValidateInput(false)]
    public SampleFile()        {
        HttpPostedFileBase httpPostedFileBase = null;
                HttpContext httpContext = null;
        

        if (MvcHtmlString.IsNullOrEmpty(Html.ValidationSummary()))
        {
            // Do Something
                }
    }
    public JsonResult Foo()
    {            return Json("Secrets", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);     }   }
}
```

I got the solution for class file.

```
private static async Task<string> ArrangeClassFileUsingRoslyn(string csCode)
{
  try
  {
      // Parse the code into a SyntaxTree.
      var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(csCode);
      // Get the root CompilationUnitSyntax.
      var root = await tree.GetRootAsync().ConfigureAwait(false) as CompilationUnitSyntax;
      return root != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(csCode) ? root.NormalizeWhitespace().ToFullString() : null;
  }
  catch (Exception objException)
  {
      return null;
  }
}
```

after using above code

**Sample.cs**

```
using System;
namespace TestFile1.Source
{
   public class SampleFile
   {
       [AllowHtml]
       public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

       [ValidateInput(false)]
       public SampleFile()
       {
           HttpPostedFileBase httpPostedFileBase = null;
           HttpContext httpContext = null;      
           if (MvcHtmlString.IsNullOrEmpty(Html.ValidationSummary()))
           {
               // Do Something
           }
       }

       public JsonResult Foo()
       {
           return Json("Secrets", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       }
       
   }
}
```

But We applied same Roslyn code in cshtml file, it is not working and lines are misalignment.

**index.cshtml:**

```
< html > < head > < meta charset = "utf-8" / > < title > @ViewBag.Title < / title > 
< link rel = "stylesheet" href = "~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" type = "text/css" / >  
< / head > < body > 
< div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" > < div class = "container" >
 < div class = "navbar-header" > 
 < button type = "button"class = "navbar-toggle" data - toggle = "collapse" data - target = ".navbar-collapse" > 
 < span class = "icon-bar" > < / span > < span class = "icon-bar" > < / span > < span class = "icon-bar" > 
 < / span > < / button >
 @Html.ActionLink("Test", "Index", "Home", new
{
area = ""
}

, new
{
@class = "navbar-brand"
}

) < / div >< / div > < / div > < div class = "container body-content" > 
}

@RenderBody() < hr / > < footer > < p > &copy;
@DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application< / p> < /footer > < /div >
 <script type = "text/javascript" src = "~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery-3.1.0.js" >
 @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) < / body > < / html >
```

Kindly suggest on alternative solution for CShtml file using Roslyn or C#.